# Simple Firebase Rules

Tags: angularjs, json, firebase, angularfire

This is my model on firebase :

```
Texts
    -KAa-aU_RjZwM7FLQcWt
         id: "5f9fe424-4323-4370-a280-9cb216dc6410"
         text: "gregegreg"
    -KAa-bZC2ouIRQ54YWWr
          id: "5f9fe424-4323-4370-a280-9cb216dc6410"
          text: "gregegreg"
```

And these are my rules :

```
"rules": {
  "Texts": {
      ".read": "auth.id === data.child('id').val()",
      ".write": true
   }
```

}

Unfortunatly, i'm still able to read All of my model TEXTS while i'm logged with another UID than 5f9fe424-4323-4370-a280-9cb216dc6410

Any idea appreciated thank you !

The authenticating part works well with angularJs and login-password :

```
var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://blinding-heat-xxxx.firebaseio.com");
            $scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth(firebaseObj);

                $scope.login = function() {

                  $scope.authData = null;
                  $scope.error = null;

                  $scope.authObj.$authWithPassword({
                        email: $scope.email,
                        password: $scope.password
                    }).then(function(authData) {
                      console.log("Logged with id:", authData.uid);

                      $scope.loadData();

                    }).catch(function(error) {
                      console.error("Auth Failed :", error);
                      $scope.error = error;
                    });
                };
```

Data is finally loaded on the web page like that :

```
$scope.loadData = function(){
var ref = new Firebase("https://blinding-heat-xxxx.firebaseio.com"); 
$scope.Texts = $firebaseArray(ref.child('Texts'));

}
```

And into the HTML , the angularJs is there :

```
 <div ng-repeat="text in Texts">text.text</div>
```

What is really strange is that the following rule works very well, for example :

```
"rules": {
  "Texts": {
      ".read": " auth != null ",
      ".write": true
   }
```

}

Comment: *Firebase engineer here* I noticed your last edit. If you're worried about people hacking your database, I suggest you create a new one, move the data over and create a new one. As an extra advantage you then get to pick the name of your database, instead of getting an auto-assigned name. Way easier to remember. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Almost there! It's actually `auth.uid` not `auth.id`.

Also, you need to provide a wildcard, a `$` variable, that applies the rule to any child below `/Texts`.

```
"rules": {
    "Texts": {
      "$text_id": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === data.child('id').val()",
        ".write": true
      }
    }
}
```

Without the wildcard, the rule is applied to the static path of `/Texts`.

Here's the output in the Simulator.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes i've changed it. But unfortunatly, it still doesn't work, it now says that "i'm not allowed to get the data", while i'm logged with 5f9fe424-4323-4370-a280-9cb216dc6410. Maybe my Firebase Json syntax is not good ?

Comment: Ah, I realized you weren't using a wildcard, so I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, do i have to mention the wildcard in another portion of the code, because i still have got the Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data, while i'm logged with uid 5f9fe424-4323-4370-a280-9cb216dc6410. As long as I change the rule to  ".read": " auth != null ", it works... But not as expected of course.

Comment: I tested this rule on a new Firebase with the same uid and data that you provided, so it should work. Can you provide how you're authenticating, and how you're accessing the data? And really, you should be using the Simulator in the dashboard to test your Rules.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot for the advices and all of the solution !, It also works now in the Firebase Rule testing. finally, it seems that it should be a ng-repeat kind of problem maybe, or about the way i try to get the data, after authenticating, but it's difficult to say for me. I have no idea how to do without a ng-repeat

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think i have to rewrite the logic of my code using  the "Storing User Data" documentation  from  https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html and finally keeps the Texts under the "users" Childs